# Creating a JSON file in python, where they are not separated by commas

Tags: json, python-3.x, spacy, doccano

I'm looking to create the below JSON file in python. I do not understand how I can have multiple dictionaries that are not separated by commas so when I use the JSON library to save the dictionary to disk, I get the below JSON;

`{"text": "Terrible customer service.", "labels": ["negative"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 1}}`

`{"text": "Really great transaction.", "labels": ["positive"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 2}}`

`{"text": "Great price.", "labels": ["positive"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 3}}`

instead of a list of dictionaries like below;

`[{"text": "Terrible customer service.", "labels": ["negative"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 1}},`

`{"text": "Really great transaction.", "labels": ["positive"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 2}},`

`{"text": "Great price.", "labels": ["positive"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 3}}]`

The difference is, in the first example, each line is a dictionary and they are not in a list or separated by commas.

Whereas in the second example, which is what I'm able to come up with is a list of dictionaries, each dictionary separated by a comma.

I'm sorry if this a stupid question I have been breaking my head over this for weeks, and have not been able to come up with a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

And thank you in advance.

Comment: perhaps you can try to explain us why would you like to keep 3 dictionaries in one file? Because if you don't want to keep it as an array (ordered list), not as object with names (`dict`), then it must be "sort-of" treated as set or some collection without order. Can you try to explain what is the desired end-effect, apart from the dicts being in one file? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: https://github.com/doccano/doccano/wiki/Import-and-Export-File-Formats    I'm trying to use Doccano to annotate NER for spacy.. and as stated in the above link, this is the accepted JSON format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LaurinNiemeyer mentioned there is no way to store multiple separated Python dictionary objects in one json file without wrapping them in a list or a dictionary or other supported data structures by Python builtin library for json. However, there is a way to workaround this, it will export files as you wanted but keep in mind that this format is not json compliant even if the file have the '.json' extension!
Let say you have the following dictionary objects that you want export:

```
dict1 = {"text": "Terrible customer service.", "labels": ["negative"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 1}}
dict2 = {"text": "Really great transaction.", "labels": ["positive"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 2}}
dict3 = {"text": "Great price.", "labels": ["positive"], "meta": {"wikiPageID": 3}}
```

To export the above dictionary objects you can simply do:

```
objs_to_export = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
with open("json_file.json", "a") as out_file:
for obj in objs_to_export:    
    json.dump(obj, out_file)
    out_file.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to store the Data in one file isn't possible with JSON.
Each JSOn file can only contain one Object. This means that you can either have one Object defined within curly braces, or an Array of objects as you mentioned.
If you want to store each Object as a JSON object you should use separate files each containing a single Object.